# How can I set default reply address in Gmail by API?

Tags: gmail-api, google-workspace

I'm trying to change "When replying to a message" (card "Accounts", section "Send mail as") to "Reply from the same address to which the message was sent" in Gmail Settings" by Gmail API (using service account that was delegated domain-wide authority) and I cannot find it in the docs (https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/v1/reference/users/settings/sendAs).

To explain why I want to do this: I'm adding certain role based Google Groups my users are member of to their send email as preferences (by the service account with domain wide authority). For example, users responsible for dealing with legal@ address are member of Google Group called legal and they have legal mails in their mailbox. When responsible users change, I just change the membership and new users receive the mails. The problem is that just the first email comes to legal@ and reply goes from john.smith@ for example. Because of that, I decided to have them reply from legal@, so those who requests something from Legal Departament knows they are communicating with whole Legal Departament and not Mr Smith only. But when Gmail doesn't automatically choose correct address when replying to the legal mail, it doesn't do what I'm trying to do.

It doesn't matter for me if I change it in admin console or by script running on all users. I wasn't able to use any of those ways.

Thank you for your help,
Martin

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm pretty certain that Gmail setting ("always reply from xx@yy, or reply from the same address to which the message is sent") is not available in the Gmail API.  It really is a client-side issue, since the email client chooses the "From:" line when composing each message or reply.

For your issue, you should be able to use Google groups as a collaborative inbox, see:  https://support.google.com/a/answer/167430?hl=en

This user note explains your use case, see:  https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/apps/siprUn9Nm9g

Comment: Collaborative inbox is a good idea, but does not satisfy my requirement to allow users to reply to _all_ emails (including those directed by a group) from their Gmail.

I understand that the From: is absolutely client-side thing. However, I as an adminstrator can say "when you use the Gmail web client, things will work as they are supposed to; you are free to use any other client, but then you are responsible for ensuring mails from yourself will work as they should". Then, if somebody uses other client (not often, through), it will be not my problem - I provided a working solution.

Comment: BTW, those role addresses are usually mapped to one employee who is responsible for handling those emails and sometimes other employee (or employees), who just need to know what's happening. I see no sense in enforcing the replying employee to watch through their personal Gmail and X role groups.

Comment: Did you look at the video linked in one of the reply notes?  https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2uzYQIRS0Ks  You can set up a variety of different mappings/policies, and you don't have to "map to one employee"  I do believe that users will have to work through the Group UI for this all to work; they can't do it entirely from within their own Gmail UI.

Comment: I _want_ to use "map to one employee" schema, the org is relatively small and doesn't have more than one employee assigned to those role-based addresses. Yes, I can use Google Groups and allow my users to send mails on behalf of the group in their gmail settings, but that's what I did. And to have them reply from legal@ when it is mail which was sent to legal@, I just need to change the gmail settings.

So yes, I'm aware how the collaboration inbox thing work. It just doesn't satisfy my needs, as the inbox isn't truly collaboration.